# How import VueJs directive globally

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I create an example in fiddler and that working, here is my code.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-demo="{myFunction: test, param: 'something'}"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  directives: {
      demo: {
          inserted: function (el, binding) {
              binding.value.myFunction( binding.value.param)
          }
      }
    },
  methods: {
        test (value) {
            alert(value)
      }
  }
})
```

When I use same code in my application like

HTML

```html
<div v-PermissionOnKeyValue="{perValue:this.$root.ViewSchool,Navigate:'Navigate',navfuncParm:'SchoolIndex'}" data-parms="SchoolIndex">
```

JS

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
// directive.
export const PermissionOnKeyValue = {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    const PermissionValue = binding.value.perValue // passed value
    if (PermissionValue) {
      console.log('from bind')
      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        binding.value.Navigate(binding.value.navfuncParm)
      })
    } else {
      el.style.backgroundColor = '#808080'
    }
  },
  update: function (el, binding) {
    console.log('from update')
    if (binding.value.perValue) {
      console.log('from update if')
      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        binding.value.Navigate(binding.value.navfuncParm)
      })
    } else {
      el.style.backgroundColor = '#808080'
    }
  }
}

Vue.directive('PermissionOnKeyValue', PermissionOnKeyValue)
```

The error is Navigate is not a function. The same code when I run on fiddler it is working, while i implement this code in my VueJs project to navigate it says that the Navigate is not a function.
What should I do

Comment: In your fiddle, `myFunction` is set to `test` which is a method in your Vue instance. In your application, `Navigate` is set to the **string** `'Navigate'` which is most definitely not a function

Comment: my Navigate function is local to the component, I import my directive globally in a js file

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. Please read it again